# When does trash become muktsa on Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, muktzeh, disposal

My granddaughters will go the candy-man in shul on Shabbos, unwrap their lolly-pops, and hand me their wrappers.  If I understand muktsa to mean something which has no purpose for me on Shabbos, then I assume those wrappers must be muktsa.  But I just can't leave them on the shul floor. So, must I take them immediately to the garbage can, or can I keep them in my pocket for some time?

Comment: The candy-man and the garbage-man ;)

Comment: I would say al pi savora that it is not muktzah untill it is placed in a garbage. Which then makes it muktzah. If this was not so then the q would apply to peeling an orange the second you finish peeling it you would have to drop it,but that is not the derech ,it only becomes set aside when it placed in a special place(bin). This is just conjecture.

Comment: I agree with @sam that the wrappers are not muktze (yet). Besides, even if they were technically mukzte, I believe one can move any muktze to get it out of the way if it is bothering people. I assume (ie, I hope!) you throw used nose tissues in the garbage after you use them, yes? Why would candy wrappers be different?

Comment: Someone told me they heard that once something becomes trash to you, you have to take it to a garbage can immediately.  I'm not sure that is practical either, especially applying the case of tissues during cold season.